# JWT Authorization multiple role in django rest framework using simple-jwt

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, authorization, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have a django website using django-rest-framework and simple-jwt for authentication. Docs: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

My website have 2 role with different capability. I have to authorize them. But I can't find how to do it. Anyone can give me an example or docs to do this function.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**permissions.py**

```
from typing import Type

from django.http.request import HttpRequest
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

from users.models import Worker


class IsWorkerUser(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to worker users.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request: Type[HttpRequest], view):
        if request.user.is_worker:
            return bool(request.user and request.user.is_worker and request.user.is_authenticated)
        return False


class IsManagerUser(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to manager users.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request: Type[HttpRequest], view):
        if request.user.is_worker:
            worker = Worker.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
            if worker:
                return bool(request.user and request.user.is_worker and request.user.is_authenticated and worker.is_manager)
        return False
```

**views.py**

```
class ManagerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsManagerUser]
```

By using permission_classes you can specify which users have permissions to do things. Also you can do it not only on viewsets but on every specific request if you want so.